# Read localstorage & pass as JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, local-storage

Im learning PHP & JSON and trying to retrieve a localstorage data (created by Domain A). if it doesnt exist, will need to query mysql and return result to clientside Domain B javascript variable.

What i understand is PHP can't access localstorage directly. But **when i place javascript on Domain A PHP file, there is Error of "unexpected token"**. I guess the output can only contain the json data that needs to be passed into Domain B javascript variable.

**I couldnt figure out how to execute javascript/ajax on Domain A php to retrieve localstorage, query Mysql then pass the result back to Domain B javascript variable.**

Just to add on that i cannot add php code to Domain B clientside page.

Anyone can help me? i have been searching for solution for days..

**(Domain A)Javascript that checks the Localstorage**

```
<script src="http://....../localstorage.js"></script>
store('ID'); //retrieve localstorage value
```

**(On Domain A) PHP+Localstorage data**

```
<?php
    //Get localstorage data
    //If localstorage is null, perform MySql query check

    $myObj->name = $result; //
    $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

    echo $myJSON;
?>
```

**(On Domain B) Javascript - Clientside**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "fileon_DomainA.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localstorage is local to the **browser**. It can only be accessed by JavaScript running in a page on the domain with which the data is associated with.

i.e. To access Domain A localstorage you must have an HTML document hosted on Domain A with JS embedded in it to read the data.

Server side code on Domain A  (or any other domain) can't read it.

JavaScript on Domain B can't ready it.

To get access to the data on Domain B you need to visit a page on Domain A that will read the data and then send it to Domain B. There are a number of approaches you could take to do this. The one that I would use would be to embed a Domain A page on Domain B using an `<iframe>` and then pass the data using `postMessage`.

Comment: hey quentin, thanks for the prompt response. Yes, i used iframe to create the Domain A localstorage key as you mentioned too.
 
PostMessage looks interesting, i haven't come across this before. 
Does this work with javascript or how does it post data between frames? Do you have some resource i could look at or any sample would be awesome :)

Comment: postMessage is a browser API for communicating between frames on different origins. [MDN has a comprehensive guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). In short, you have an event listener in one domain and then you call postMessage from the other in order to trigger that event. You can include data in the event object.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin !! I see how this works now and able to pass variables :D